# How to import an input variable to a module in python

Tags: python, importerror

Hi I'm new to python and I'm creating a program to count all palindromes in a user input. The thing is I have to use a module. I have to import the variables inp and count from main.py to modules.py Also I'm not allowed to edit main.py

Sample input:
sis Hannah is the name of the nun who talked to mom
Sample output:
There were 4 palindromes.

This code works but I have to press the enter key twice because I have two inp variables:

main.py:

```
from modules import palindrome_check as pc, print_output as po

inp = input()
count = pc(inp)
po(count)
```

modules.py:

```
def palindrome_check(inp):
    return inp == inp[::-1] if len(inp) > 1 else None

inp = [i for i in input().lower().split() if palindrome_check(i)]
count = 0
for i in inp:
    if palindrome_check(i):
        count += 1
def print_output(num):
    if count == 0:
        print("There were no palindromes.")
    else:
        if count == 1:
            print("There was one palindrome.")
        else:
            print("There were {} palindromes.".format(count))
```

I've tried this:

modules.py:

```
def palindrome_check(inp):
    from modules import inp
    return inp == inp[::-1] if len(inp) > 1 else None

inp = [i for i in input().lower().split() if palindrome_check(i)]
for i in inp:
    if palindrome_check(i):
        count += 1
def print_output(num):
    from modules import count
    if count == 0:
        print("There were no palindromes.")
    else:
        if count == 1:
            print("There was one palindrome.")
        else:
            print("There were {} palindromes.".format(count))
```

But I keep getting this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'inp' from partially initialized module 'modules' (most likely due to a circular import)

I've watched youtube videos and read other forums to solve this but nothing seems to work. Even the Import *filename format.

Comment: What do you expect to achieve with `from modules import count` inside `modules.py`? It is circular import, cause you are using that in the same module. Your main should have an "entry point" (the usual boilerplate `if name=="__main__":` thingy) and your palindrome function should iterate in its body OR use another helper function to do so imho.

Comment: "I have to import the variables inp and count from main.py to modules.py Also I'm not allowed to edit main.py." This doesn't make any sense. main.py already imports from modules, modules shouldn't be importing back from main. Either you've misunderstood or your teacher has no idea what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the purpose of your program, but you can simplify it in a couple of ways.

1. **Keep everything in one file**: `modules.py`. The program is simple and there is no need to use multiple files.
2. Use `__name__=="__main__":` to control the way Python runs your program, as mentioned in the comment. Here is the full code snippet:

```
    def palindrome_check(inp):
        return inp == inp[::-1] if len(inp) > 1 else None
    
    
    def count_palindromes(i):
        all_inputs = []
        for _ in range(i):
            user_inp = input().lower().strip()
            all_inputs.append(user_inp)
    
        count = 0
        for i in all_inputs:
            if palindrome_check(i):
                count += 1
        return count
    
    def print_output(c):
        if c == 0:
            print("There were no palindromes.")
        else:
            if c == 1:
                print("There was one palindrome.")
            else:
                print("There were {} palindromes.".format(c))
    
    
    if __name__=="__main__":
        num_palindrones = count_palindromes(2)
        print_output(num_palindrones)
```

Comment: Your code is all indented an extra level.

Comment: Also, the asker's assignment provides main.py, which can't be edited, and requires them to write modules.py.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I didn't misunderstand your point. There is an error in the code, namely **circular import**. For example `A.py` (inside `import B`) and `B.py` (inside `import A`). To work around this, make your code like this:

`modules.py` should be like this:

```py
def palindrome_check(inp):
    return inp == inp[::-1] if len(inp) > 1 else None

def print_output(count):
    if count == 0:
        print("There were no palindromes.")
    else:
        if count == 1:
            print("There was one palindrome.")
        else:
            print("There were {} palindromes.".format(count))
```

`main.py` should be like this:

```py
from modules import palindrome_check as pc, print_output as po

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inp = input()
    count = pc(inp)
    inp = [i for i in input().lower().split() if pc(i)]
    for i in inp:
        if pc(i):
            count += 1
    po(count)
```

Comment: The asker's assignment provides main.py, which can't be edited, and requires them to write modules.py.